# How and when to use a 'Extract String Resource"?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, resources, android-resources

I know this may be a dumb question to some, but what exactly does 'Extract String Resource" in Android Studio do? I know that it updates the strings.xml file, but why do we extract it? What is the point of it? And I'm not sure when to use it?
Thank you for your help and time!
(I'm new to Android Studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do we extract it?

To take a literal string, hard-coded somewhere, and replace it with a string resource and a reference to that string resource. So, you turn something like:

```
btnSomething.setText("Foo");
```

with:

```
btnSomething.setText(R.string.foo);
```

and a `<string>` resource named `foo` with a default value of `Foo`.

Principally, you use string resources for translations. So, `res/values/strings.xml` might hold US English strings, but `res/values-fr/strings.xml` would hold French strings, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much! So do I have to extract the string if I ONLY want it to be in English? This app will probably be only in English, so does that mean I still have to extract the string? But now I do understand why we use it thanks to you, thank you!

Comment: @MarkPrescher: You don't have to use string resources if you do not want to. I would recommend using them, just so that you get comfortable with the practice. Just because *this* app will be English-only does not mean *every app you ever work on* will be in a single language. Plus, if this code will be seen by anyone other than yourself (code review, portfolio as part of a job application, etc.), *they* might expect you to use string resources.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really do appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @CommonsWare's answer, using string resources also helps when you need to reuse the same string in different places. So instead of hard-coding the string literal in each case, you just use the `<string>` resource.

This also makes your code easier to maintain, e.g for cases in which you need to change the string, you just go to your `res/values/strings.xml` and modify that single string instead tracking down wherever you hard-coded that literal string.

Comment: Thank you, the app needs to be regularly maintained and updated! I'll definitely take this into consideration!